# Rails: Link_to helper with :controller, :action, :class, and embedded html tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm trying to create a pretty complex link where I need it too look like this `<a><li>Link text</li></a>`. Right now I have this:

```
<% ["Philosophy", "Team", "Local Vendors"].each do |link_name| %>
    <% if params[:action] == link_name.downcase.sub(" ", "_") %>
    <%= link_to {:controller => :philosophy, :action => link_name.downcase.sub(" ", "_").to_sym}, {:class => "selected"} do %>
        <li><%= link_name %></li>
    <% end %>
    <% else %>
    <%= link_to :controller => :philosophy, :action => link_name.downcase.sub(" ", "_").to_sym do %>
        <li><%= link_name %></li>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

But instead of producing a link that looks like `<a href="philosophy/philosophy" class="selected"><li>Philosophy</li></a>` it is giving me

```
<a href="/philosophy/philosophy?class=selected">
   <li>Philosophy</li>
</a>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will resolve your issue:

```
<%= link_to({:controller => :philosophy, :action => link_name.downcase.sub(" ", "_").to_sym}, {:class => "selected"}) do %>
```

I'm surprised you're not getting an error at that line without the surrounding parenthesis.

Comment: This is why I'm confused you didn't get an error. The `do` proc was attempting to be provided to the hash containing your selected class. When you wrap the link_to parameters with the parenthesis it is instead being applied to the link_to method which correctly yields to it. Just testing this on Ruby 1.9.3 on one of my Rails apps, I received an error as expected. Glad it's fixed though! :)